# How to have the Scheduler retry a task when it has failed with a specific error code?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have a cmd file which executes an application (exe) that can return a specific error code in some cases. This cmd is launched by the Scheduler every day.
If it failed with this specific error, I want to be able to reschedule and retry the task every 30mn up to 3 times or for the next 2 hours before giving up until the next day.

How can I pass the error code to the scheduler to have it retry automatically (if at all possible) or how can I create a new temporary fail-over scheduled task from the initial cmd?

It should run mainly on Win2003 and Win2008 servers (x32 or x64).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try to run your command, wait on failure and rerun it. you can use `ping` to fake a `sleep` command (or get a sleep.exe from the resource toolkit or hack your own or use vbscript). anyway, just schedule this script daily:

```
@echo first try here
@if not errorlevel 42 goto end
@ping 127.0.0.1 -w 1000 > NUL

@echo second try here
@if not errorlevel 42 goto end
@ping 127.0.0.1 -w 2000 > NUL

@echo third try here
@if not errorlevel 42 goto end
@ping 127.0.0.1 -w 3000 > NUL

@echo will try again tomorrow

:end
@echo finish %errorlevel%
```

replace `42`with the exit code your are interested in and replace `-w 1000` with the time in milliseconds you want to wait  between each retry.

Comment: That's more or less the workaround I had in mind but I am a bit concerned about leaving it ping or sleep for 30mn instead of rescheduling. Any potential drawback with pinging for a big chunk of time?

Comment: i do not know. you can also grab a sleep.exe from somewhere, if that makes you feel more comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a script (batch file) to call your application and test the error code and conditionally re-execute it or exit.

Then schedule the script instead of the application.